# Wire Prep for Spring Terminal Block

Tags: wire-terminals, screw-terminal, terminal-block

I am assembling an electrical system for a project, and I'm using [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086138Z1G) terminal blocks because of their ease of use. Currently my wire ranges from 14awg stranded to 20awg stranded (20awg has some pretty fine strands). I'm connecting them bare to the terminal block, and I've looked around and found ferrules that are used, but **I was wondering if tinned wires would work?** I know they're not safe for other terminal block mechanisms, but because these are spring-action, is there any risk of the solder being destroyed, or will the spring mechanism always keep it secure?

Worst case I'll probably just buy ferrules and a crimper.

Thanks!

Comment: I think a tinned wire would mate properly, but the wire might have a tendency to break where it exits the block due to the solder stiffening the wire inside the insulation. I would do it in a pinch as long as the wires weren't going to be yanked around. Ferrules are faster and superior though, and crimpers can be found very cheap from china.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reliably secure stranded wire in terminal block?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259690/how-to-reliably-secure-stranded-wire-in-terminal-block)

Comment: I have used  ferrules in industrial equipment without any problems. That is how it came in from Auckland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the data with the terminal states this: "【Universal Compatibility】 This Wire Connector is suitable for solid and flexible wire. Connect any combination of solid, stranded, and flexible copper wires. Suit for solid wire 0.08-4.0mm² /28-12 AWG, flexible wire 0.5-2.5mm² /20-14 AWG. It is widely used in distribution boxes, control cabinets, switchgear, complete sets of equipment, machinery etc." I normally tin my smaller gauge wires just to keep them from spreading out at the terminal block, this makes it much easier to insert.

Comment: I have used  ferrules in industrial equipment with no problems. It is your choice, what feels the best to you.